# Access apply filter macro for individual words in single text box

Tags: ms-access

I have a database which is based on travel insurance and the two columns are name and cost

In the name column I type in the names as the following format

```
Name  airline  credit card
```

I have linked a macro to a button on a form with the following code:

```
On click:
 Apply filter:
   Where condition: name like "*" &[text box entry on form]& "*" Or airline like  "*" &[text box entry on form]& "*" Or credit_card like  "*" &[text box entry on form]& "*"
```

However when I search for " name credit card" and leave out the airline wanting all the bookings under that name and credit card irrelevant of the airline it doesn't return anything. How can I change the macro where condition so that I would be able to search for each word on the text box independently?

Comment: Enter values separated by commas and code would parse the string. Making life hard for yourself. Conventional approach would be 3 controls. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html. Name is a reserved word, should not use reserved words as names for anything.